# How to apply transaction roll back in database object in .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, database, web-applications

Does anyone know how to apply transaction roll back in database object in .net c#?

Example: 
I have the following code originally:

```
   protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      try {
         m_test = CreateTest();
      } catch{}
   }


   private Db.Test CreateTest()
   {
           var test= new Test();
           test.Title = sTitle.SelectedValue;
           test.FirstName = sFirstName.Text;
           test.LastName = sLastName.Text;
           test.PhoneHome = sHomePhone.Text;
           test.PhoneWork = sWorkPhone.Text;
           test.PhoneMobile = sMobile.Text;
           test.EmailAddress = sEmail.Text;
           test.Save();

           return test;
   }
```

Then I trying to apply transaction roll back action into the code and applied the following code inside... then I stack under the method CreateTest. I got no idea how could I applied the code for the database object

```
       protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

          SqlConnection connDB = new SqlConnection();
          SqlCommand cmdExecuting = new SqlCommand();

          try {
             connDB = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
             cmdExecuting.Connection = connDB;
             connDB.Open();
             cmdExecuting.Transaction = connDB.BeginTransaction();

             m_test = CreateTest(cmdExecuting);

            if (m_test != 0) {
                 cmdExecuting.Transaction.Rollback();
                 return;
            }
          } catch{}
       }


   private Db.Test CreateTest(SqlCommand  cmdExecuting)
   {
           var test= new Test();
           test.Title = sTitle.SelectedValue;
           test.FirstName = sFirstName.Text;
           test.LastName = sLastName.Text;
           test.PhoneHome = sHomePhone.Text;
           test.PhoneWork = sWorkPhone.Text;
           test.PhoneMobile = sMobile.Text;
           test.EmailAddress = sEmail.Text;
           test.Save();

           return test;
   }
```

Does anyone know how can I code in the CreateTest() in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class, which provides several benefits including

- Automatic transaction enlistment of
  connections made within scope
- Automatic rollback of transactions
  when exceptions occur
- In my opinion it also makes the code
  a bit more legible since it reduces
  the amount of code needed

.

```
try    
{   
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())     
    {                                   
        m_test = CreateTest();          
        scope.Complete(); // Commit transaction     
    }    
}    
catch (Exception ex)    
{
    // Transaction is automatically rolled back
}
```

Also, see the article [Introducing System.Transactions in the .NET Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx) for a great starting point.

Comment: I tried the following way to do my coding, but error display : The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions

Comment: @Jin: If  you are working with several machines over a network, then make sure that the Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) Service runs on all machines, the clients as well as servers. This service is installed on all Windows systems by default, but it may be configured so that it is not yet started automatically.

Comment: @Jin: It sounds like the MSDTC is not configured. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899191 or http://perezj.blogspot.com/2008/06/transaction-manager-has-disabled-its.html

Answer (score 1):

you can take help of the following you dont need to take care of transaction at backend sqltransaction object will take care of it. you can put this code in your own event whichever is responsible for inserting the data in the database

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Northwind;uid=sa;pwd=sa;");
      myConnection.Open();

      // Start a local transaction
      SqlTransaction myTrans = myConnection.BeginTransaction();

      SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
      myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
      myCommand.Transaction = myTrans;
      try
      {
        myCommand.CommandText = "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (100, 'Description')";
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCommand.CommandText = "delete * from Region where RegionID=101";

        // Attempt to commit the transaction. 
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myTrans.Commit();
        Response.Write("Both records are written to database.");
      }
      catch (Exception ep)
      {
        // Attempt to roll back the transaction. 
        myTrans.Rollback();
        Response.Write(ep.ToString());
        Response.Write("Neither record was written to database.");
      }
      finally
      {
        myConnection.Close();
      }
    }
```

Comment: @ forsvarir :ok but i dont think anything is unclear if you have any doubts point out

Comment: You should put the rollback in a try/catch as it can throw an exception if the connection is terminated or the transaction is already rolled back on the server.

Comment: @cdel if you will have a closer look it's already in the catch block :)

Comment: The catch block will catch only the exceptions thrown in the try above. If you have doubts just put a throw in your catch block, if it were as you say you'll end up with an infinite loop.